# Remove all lines from file with duplicate value in field, including the first occurrence

Tags: unix, awk, terminal, uniq

I would like to remove all the lines in my data file that contain a value in column 2 that is repeated in column 2 in other lines.

I've sorted by the value in column 2, but can't figure out how to use uniq for just the values in one field as the values are not necessarily of the same length.

Alternately, I can remove lines with the duplicate using an awk one-liner like

```
awk -F"[,]" '!_[$2]++'
```

but this retains the line with the first incidence of the repeated value in col 2.

As an example, if my data is

```
a,b,c
c,b,a
d,e,f
h,i,j
j,b,h
```

I would like to remove ALL lines (including the first) where b occurs in the second column.
Like this:

```
d,e,f
h,i,j
```

Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: Not necessarily with awk. I was originally looking for a solution with grep or uniq, but am open to anything.

Comment: Is the output order of the lines important?

Comment: no, the output order of the lines doesn't matter. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is not important then the following should work:

```
awk -F, '
!seen[$2]++ {
    line[$2] = $0
}
END { 
    for(val in seen)
        if(seen[val]==1) 
          print line[val]
}' file
```

**Output**

```
h,i,j
d,e,f
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with grep:

```
grep -v -E '\b,b,\b' text.txt
```

**Content of the file:**

```
$ cat text.txt 
a,b,c
c,b,a
d,e,f
h,i,j
j,b,h
a,n,b
b,c,f

$ grep -v -E '\b,b,\b' text.txt 
d,e,f
h,i,j
a,n,b
b,c,f
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this works great for the example data, but my actual data contains hundreds of different gene names in col 2. I'm not sure if/how I could adapt this...

Comment: @user3288154 what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @user3288154 redirect it to a file, and that's all.

Comment: When I use this on my file, all the lines still appear, including ones with the same value in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

Some different awk:

```
awk -F, '
   BEGIN {f=0}
   FNR==NR {_[$2]++;next}
   f==0 {
      f=1
      for(j in _)if(_[j]>1)delete _[j]
   }
   $2 in _
' file file
```

**Explanation**

The `awk` passes through the file twice - that's why it appears twice at the end. On the first pass (when `FNR==NR`) I count the number of times each column 2 appears in array `_[]`. At the end of the first pass, I then delete all elements of `_[]` where that element has been seen more than once. Then, on the second pass, I print lines whose second field appears in `_[]`.

Comment: Excellent! Pleased to be of help.